# How to determine \$\tau\$ for such a case?

Tags: transistors, bjt, frequency-response, common-emitter

[image: Circuit]

In the above circuit when I want to calculate the impedance seen by each of the capacitors, should I short or open the other one? Or which ever one is more convenient?

In order to find \$\small f_{C_E}\$ for example (cutoff-frequency due to \$\small C_E\$) I use the formula:

$$f_{C_E} = \frac{1}{2\pi C_E\cdot R_\text{eq}}$$

where \$R_\text{eq}\$ is the impedance seen by \$\small C_E\$. So I kill all independent sources and put a test source in place of \$\small C_E\$. What should I do with \$ \small C_C \$?

Comment: Why do you need to do either?

Comment: *should I short or open the other one*: Either I'm misunderstanding something very much, or this makes no sense at all – even in a circuit made out of linear components, where you could turn off all but one voltage or current source, one by one, and in the end add up the results for each component. (In that case, it would also not be an "one or the other", but "each of them in succession", and for sources, not capacitors. BUT! as said, this doesn't work here, either, as this is not a linear circuit.)

Comment: Anyways, this is a homework/learning assignment without an own attempt and too many unclear points; please **edit** your question to show exactly, including how far you get with that, how you would approach this. As it currently is written, this is impossible to answer, because all options you propose are very wrong.

Comment: Edit made. Hopefully my question is more clear now. I apologize for hastily writing it initially.

Comment: @AhsonYousef thanks for the edit. Sadly, it's **still** not clear what you mean with "shorting" and "opening": it still makes no sense. Please explain exactly what you would have done. Also, I'm not used to this equation; it does make sense, kind of, but you need to realize that $R_{eq}$ depends on the time-varying voltage over $C_E$, so I'm not convinced it will be easy to use this formula.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right it is rather difficult finding \$R_{eq}\$ this way so I just found the cutoff frequencies using the transfer function!

Comment: Ahson Yousef The answer is relatively simple: In practice, for finding the input impedance at the emitter node, it does not matter if Cc is there or not. And the same applies to the impedance at the collector node (seen by Cc). In this case, the capacitor Ce has no (major) influence.

Comment: @AhsonYousef you can solve for the time constant with some assumptions. Check my answer.

Comment: Your system is a second-order system so you have two different time constants. The coupling capacitor \$C_C\$ brings a zero at the origin while the emitter capacitor \$C_E\$ brings a second zero. A possible approach is to consider a frequency band where \$C_C\$ is a short circuit and you end up with one natural time constant involving \$C_E\$. Turn the input source off (replace it by a short circuit), short \$V_{cc}\$ to ground and replace the transistor by its small-signal model. Then determine the resistance driving \$C_E\$ in this mode. It will give you the pole. The zero requires an NDI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily find the open-circuit impedance seen by Cc with the assumption that Ce is producing an AC ground. This makes the voltage controlled current source of Q0 equal 0, because the input signal is also grounded when computing time constants; therefore, the voltage across rpi, which controls the vccs of the transistor, is equal to 0.

With that assumption, you can do KVL around this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiMIeR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 and R2 are in series. Therefore, the 1st order time constant due Cc equals:
$$
\tau_{C_c} = C_c (R_L + R_C)
$$

Comment: Do you think that this result is valid only because Ce produces a signal ground? And what about rce?

Comment: @LvW Yes, it's an approximation. And I assumed Rce to be very large compared to Rc. If not, then you can also calculate it, but from what I've computed, the expression is much more complicated.

Comment: Yes I got the same result using the transfer function. For the overall question it seems computing the transfer function is necessary!

Comment: @AhsonYousef if I understood correctly, your question is about finding the 1st order time constants due to the different storage elements in your circuit (in this case, the capacitors). If so, then it is NOT necessary to know the transfer function if you want to know the time constants (thus, the pole of your circuit). However, for the zerso, you do need to compute the transfer function, as they depend on where you define your inputs and outputs.

Comment: @ErnestoG That was the background of my comment - when rce is sufficiently large, it does not matter at all if the emitter is grounded or not. More than that - what do you mean with "current source equal 0 " ? What matters is the internal resistance of the source and NOT the current.

Comment: @LvW You read it wrong, I said the voltage controlled current source (vccs). If the argument is that Ce makes AC ground, then the vpi voltage controlling the (vccs) equals 0V since it's grounded on both sides, then the vccs is zero or an open circuit. 

I do not see how assuming ro being very long leads to the same answer procedurally (and without AC ground). If I do that, then I'm left with sort of a problem with the vccs being controlled by vpi across the rpi resistor but being fed by a vccs controlled by vpi. So seems like something is undefined.

Comment: @LvW if you can show that line of thought as an answer, would be interesting to see. As far as I see it, the circuit cannot be analyzed like that, but perhaps you see something I don't.

Comment: *ro being very high, not long 

Comment: @ErnestoG I agree that you spoke about the VCCS. But this current source will not deliver a current of zero value because Ce grounds the emitter. Instead, we require that the input signal Vs must be zero during determination of the BJTs output resistance at the collector node. THIS is the reason that the BJT cannot deliver a signal current through the collector node.

Comment: @LvW indeed, BOTH emitter and base have to grounded in order for the vccs to provide 0 current and be an open. That's what I've been saying all along. I didn't say I grounded the base because I thought it was obvious it must be so

Comment: @ErnestoG What do you mean with "vccs to provide 0 current"? Dont forget that the BJT must have a correct bias point with the proper DC collector current. Remember that I spoke about a "signal current" of zero value! That is a big difference.

Comment: @LvW What you say is not true. For example, a common base amplifier has a small signal ground at the base but still, the "signal current" (as you call it) is non-zero. The voltage difference between the base and emitter has to be zero for a zero signal current (through VCCS), as ErnestoG has explained.

Comment: @sarthak I cannot follow you. Please explain to me: Which is of my sentences is "not true? All I wanted to say is that the input signal must be zero when we want to calculate the output impedance of an amplifier. But this is NOT identical to the requirement that the vccs must "provide 0 current" (as stated earlier). At first, there must be a DC bias current and secondly the VCCS must be able to deliver a current caused by the test voltage at the output (feedback effect).

Comment: @LvW I never said that the vccs must provide 0 current. Can you please show me where did I say that? What I said is that the vccs provides zero current in the analysis as a consequence of the controlling voltage vpi being 0 due to the input signal being grounded and the source as well.

Comment: @ErnestoG Perhaps just a misunderstanding - however, look at the second line of your detailed answer and the 1st line of your 6th comment. At least, the sentences are misleading because you did not make any distinction between signal and DC currents.

Comment: @LvW You said that a zero input signal, Vs, is the reason that BJT cannot deliver signal current. This is not true. It is only true if the emitter voltage is also zero.

Comment: @sarthak In the circuit under discussion, do you see any external signal voltage at the emitter node? I cannot follow you when - suddenly - you want to discuss a common-base stage.

Comment: @LvW because it seemed you kept on saying that it's enough for the input to be ground  (and somehow assuming ro is big too) to arrive at my result. I disagree with that statement and seems sarthak does as well. So, how about we stop this long and boring thread and you write up an answer using your assumptions? I'd gladly read it and vote it if I'm convinced.

Comment: @ErnestoG No problem - I just can repeat what I have written here already: "All I wanted to say is that the input signal must be zero when we want to calculate the output impedance of an amplifier. But this is NOT identical to the requirement that the vccs must "provide 0 current" (as stated earlier). At first, there must be a DC bias current and secondly the VCCS must be able to deliver a current caused by the test voltage at the output (feedback effect)." For clearity I should add: With "input signal" I mean a voltage between B and E because the BJT is voltage-controlled.

Answer (score 6):

To solve this exercise, you must first replace the transistor by its small-signal model so that you can work on a linear circuit. I have used the [hybrid-\$\pi\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid-pi_model) model in the below picture:

[image]

Now you see two capacitors. As they have independent state variables, this is a second-order circuit. However, people usually consider the \$C_C\$ dc-coupling capacitor large enough to be replaced by a short circuit in the analysis band. The circuit then simplifies to the last schematic.

Ok, where do you go from there? This is a first-order circuit and its transfer function \$H\$ obeys the following expression: \$H=H_0\frac{1+\frac{s}{\omega_z}}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}}\$. Below are the steps to obtain this transfer function:

1. redraw the circuit with \$v_s\$ back and remove \$C_E\$ from the circuit. This is the condition for \$s=0\$. Determine the gain \$H_0\$ linking \$V_{out}\$ to \$V_{in}\$ in this condition.
2. Then, to determine the time constant and the pole, install a test generator across the connecting terminals of \$C_E\$ and determine the resistance driving it:

[image]

In this circuit, the emitter current source is zeroed in ac (an open circuit) and replaced by its output resistance \$r_0\$. If you do the maths ok, you should find for \$R\$ the output resistance of the emitter paralleled with the current source output resistance. If this latter is infinite, then the output resistance combined with the capacitor forms the natural time constant of this circuit.

3. For the zero, determine the condition for which you would observe a *null* on the output meaning that for some impedance conditions, the collector current becomes zero, implying a zeroed base current and thus, an open emitter:

[image]

There you go, you have the complete transfer function and you can compare the ac response between a resistor classically loading the emitter or a current source as in your example. A quick SPICE simulation confirms the zero approaching the origin with a current source when \$r_0\$ is infinite:

[image]